# Dragging a file on Mail.app doesn't attach it

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, attachments

When dragging any file onto the Mail app icon, a compose window with the file attached should open.

Since quite a while (I believe since macOS 12.4), the compose window only contains the file name in angle brackets and no attachment.

(Dragging a file into the compose window as opposed to the app icon works fine.)

Is this a known issue? Any idea how to fix?

Comment: It works correctly for me. What file type? Is the source destination on a special location, e.g. network drive, Cloud etc? Do you have "Protect Mail Activity" enabled in Preferences > Privacy?  However, it's a lot quicker/easier to right-click and choose Share > Mail than dragging a file across the desktop to the Dock.

Comment: @benwiggy The file type doesn't matter, happens with all files. They're on the local volume and the problem also occurs for Share > Mail. "Protect Mail Activity" also doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this as a bug (FB10791772) to Apple and – you may not believe it – I received a quick confirmation including a workaround:

The issue occurs when under "Edit" > "Include Attachments With Replies", "Never" or "When Adding Recipients" is selected.

If "Always" or "Ask" is selected instead, the problem no longer occurs. Until the bug is fixed, this is a viable workaround for me.